# Auto Change image specific period of time

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the images from array every specific period time. But my code do not work, need help please.

```html
<body>
<div id="one">one</div>
<img src="" id="photo2">
<script>
    var one = document.getElementById("one");
    var photo2 = document.getElementById("photo2");

    var links = ["03.gif","04.gif","05.gif","06.gif","07.gif"];
    one.onclick = function(){
        _SlidePic(0);
    };

    function _SlidePic(i){
        if (i < links.length){
            photo2.src = links[i];
            i++;
            id = setInterval(_SlidePic(i),1000);
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should create some variable for ex. index which will hold current index, then you will do only `setInterval(() => photo2.src = links[(index++)%links.length], 1000);` this should work

Comment: what is the procedure taken in order to change the images ?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` takes a function like this:
`setInterval(functionName, 1000)` not like this: `setInterval(functionName(), 1000)`.
Also I moved your index variable out of the function for a better performance.
The `setInterval` call is now in the `onClick` listener to only be called once. You had it in the function itself and it would call itself every time that the picture changes.

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var photo2 = document.getElementById("photo2");

var links = ["03.gif", "04.gif", "05.gif", "06.gif", "07.gif"];
var idx = 0
one.onclick = function() {
  _SlidePic();
  setInterval(_SlidePic, 1000);
};

function _SlidePic() {
  if (idx < links.length) {
    photo2.src = links[idx];
    idx++;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <img src="" id="photo2">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` takes the function that will be executed. You have to define a function inside `setInterval` instead of calling it.

You can fix it into two ways without changing structure of your code.

1. You can use `bind` property to make i accessible inside `_SlidePic` function.

```js
  var one = document.getElementById("one");
var photo2 = document.getElementById("photo2");

var links = ["03.gif","04.gif","05.gif","06.gif","07.gif"];
one.onclick = function(){
    _SlidePic(0);
};

 function _SlidePic(i){
    if (i < links.length){
        photo2.src = links[i];
        i++;
        id = setInterval(_SlidePic.bind(this, i), 1000);
      
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <img src="" id="photo2">
</body>
```

2. You can define function inside `setInterval` and call `SlidePic` inside that function like below...

```js
  var one = document.getElementById("one");
var photo2 = document.getElementById("photo2");

var links = ["03.gif","04.gif","05.gif","06.gif","07.gif"];
one.onclick = function(){
    _SlidePic(0);
};

 function _SlidePic(i){
    if (i < links.length){
        photo2.src = links[i];
        i++;
        id = setInterval(function(){
          _SlidePic(i)
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <img src="" id="photo2">
</body>
```